# How to disable C3 chart's select points on line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I have created this graph in c3 chart. Those two circles on red line are selected point. When I click on these points, they are going invisible. Also when I click on other points of green and red line. They are also selecting like these two. Is there any procedure to disable selection of other points ?
[image]

I don't want to select other points. When I click on other points, they are also selecting like
[image]

I am declaring c3's selected points by :

```
chart_tracker.select(['data2'],[19,47,]);
```

Comment: So the red circles are selected by default and you want to disable selection on the green line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the click event that c3 listens to to update these circles (add after chart is set up):

```
d3.select("#chart").selectAll(".c3-event-rect").on("click", null);
```

change #chart to whatever the id of your chart is ^^^

you might need to put this in c3's onrendered callback if your chart updates as the click function may get restored by c3